# MYSQL - Get data from INNER JOIN with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have two tables for get impression and click

```
Product
+----+--------+
| PID| brand  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Ford   |
|  2 | Toyota |
|  6 | Holden |
+----+--------+

States
+----+--------+------+--------+------------+
| ID | PID    |CLICKS| VIEWS  | DATE       |
+----+--------+------+--------+------------+
|  1 | 1      |   1  |   0    |  12/12/2015|
|  1 | 1      |   1  |   0    |  12/12/2015|
|  2 | 2      |   1  |   0    |  12/12/2015|
|  3 | 2      |   0  |   1    |  12/12/2015|
|  3 | 1      |   0  |   1    |  12/12/2015|
+----+--------+------+--------+------------+
```

I need to get some result like this

```
+--------+------+--------+
| PID    |CLICKS| VIEWS  |
+--------+------+--------+
| 1      |   2  |   1    |
| 2      |   1  |   0    |
+--------+------+--------+
```

is it possible? i have tried too many times its coming faults data

Comment: Do a JOIN with a GROUP BY.

Comment: lookup how `group by` works

Comment: `SELECT stats_property.date, property.idproperty, COUNT(stats_property.clicks='1') AS A, COUNT(stats_property.impression='0') AS I  FROM property INNER JOIN  stats_property ON property.idproperty = stats_property.idproperty group by property.idproperty, stats_property.clicks`   I Have try this way its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  PID,
  SUM(CLICKS) as CLICKS,
  SUM(VIEWS) as VIEWS
FROM States
GROUP BY PID
```

If you need 0 for all Products

```
SELECT
  Products.PID,
  SUM(CLICKS) as CLICKS,
  SUM(VIEWS) as VIEWS
FROM Products 
     LEFT JOIN States ON States.PID=Products.PID
GROUP BY Products.PID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this by Inner Join.

```
SELECT t1.pid, sum(clicks) as CLICKS, sum(views) as VIEWS
FROM Product as t1 INNER JOIN States as t2 ON t1.pid=t2.pid GROUP BY t1.pid
```

Comment: INNER JOIN is futile. States table is enough. If all products are necessary then OUTER JOIN should be used